# How to structure folders for resources and layouts for the same size device but different DisplayMetrics.densityDpi?

Tags: android

We are using two different tablets with following display specs:

**Tablet A:**

```
Screen size -- 7"; 480 x 800

Taskbar height -- 36px
```

**Tablet B:**

```
Screen size -- 7"; 480 x 800
taskbar height -- 48px
```

`DisplayMetrics.xdpi` and `DisplayMetrics.ydpi` for both tablets are same and equal to 160 and 160.42 respectively.
 However, `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi` for tablet A is being shown as DENSITY_LOW while for Tablet B it is being 
shown as DENSITY_MEDIUM. The folders (for drawables and layouts) accessed by the two tablets match the densityDpi 
values.

The questions are:
1) How can these two devices have different pixel density?
2) What is best way of structuring folders for resources and layouts in such a situation?

I find the second issue extremely confounding as a genuinely LDPI screen with a smaller size will access resources 
and layouts from the same folders as Tablet A but will, most probably, the result will be displayed badly.